# dynamic handlebar table creation

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

i cant dynamically create table using handlethe bars. "arrays" is an array of objects (each object has id, name, description, and category).

I dont know why the code below worked for li element insertion but not for table. Can some one help?

```
        let arrays = [{ id: 0, name: "name0", description: "this is is name0","category":1} ,{ id: 1, name: "name1", description: "this is is name1","category":2},...]
let template =Handlebars.compile($('#template1').html())
let html = template({arrays: arrays})

$('#div1').append(html)          

    <template id="template1">
        <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>description</th>
            </tr>

            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {{#each arrays}}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{id}}</td>
                    <td>{{name}}</td>
                    <td>{{desciption}}</td>
                </tr>
                {{/each}}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </template>
```

the expectation is a table with just id name and description but not category

Comment: update: i dont know whay iteration is not working in creating table only. the above code works fine when create any tags elements like <li>, <p>...etc.

Answer (score 0):

you're trying to insert a template after having processed the compiling. Your template won't work except for the parts that are not related to handlebars. If you want to process the template once you've done the insert in your HTML file then try to do your template compiling after the append and not before.

Usually I use jquery $(document).ready(...) to do such delaying.